# why IE10 open large html(large js) too slow?

Tags: javascript, html, web, large-files

The problem is that we open a large html with ie10 is too slow, but with ie8 or ie11 is very fast,anyone know why? In the sample code “boundaryCoors” is a too long text and the html size almost 18M.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
   <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var MAP_LAYER_DATA ={ 
                districtName:"全国", 
                districtNo:"100000000", 
                districtLayer:"province", 
                boundaryCoors: [[80.508, 20.825,130.111, 50.555]], 
                subDistrict:[ {
            districtName:"北京市",
            districtNo:"110100000",
            districtLayer:"country",
            bounds:{left:115.42374,bottom:39.43962819,right:117.5066874,top:41.06081826},
            boundaryCoors:"very long text",
            subDistrict:[]}];
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="tundra">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a link for this sample?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7vvq86ghd1ht09u/2.zip Open 2.html on localmachine.

Comment: Oh, dropbox is blocked in my company. Need to check later.

Comment: @VitorCanova Can you give me an email?I will send the sample code to you.thank you very much.

Comment: Just tested at home in IE11 and it was very slow. It draw a blue circle but spent a lot of time to do this. Maybe take a look at UI Responsiveness in developer tools.